# Function always returns numeric(0)

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R, so I apologize if this is a trivially easy question. I tried Googling, but could not find examples that seemed completely relevant (most examples only have 1 function argument).

I have a simple function representing a basic linear model in 2 dimensions:

```
y <- function(x, w) {
  temp <- w[0] + x*w[1]
  return(temp)
}
```

When I use it the way I expect, I get:

```
> y(1,c(-0.3,0.5))
numeric(0)
```

When I try an incorrect input, same thing!

```
> y(1,2)
numeric(0)
```

Ultimately, my goal is to be able to have a vector, X, that can be passed in as the argument. For example:

```
> y(c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2))
```

Comment: Vectors in R are 1-indexed, not 0-indexed.

Comment: Just to be more explicit before this gets closed, the first element of a vector would be selected like `w[1]` not `w[0]`.

Comment: one of R's more eclectic features is that it doesn't through an error for vector[0]. It's quite easy to be bitten by this.

Comment: @joran hello my R doppleganger ... nice name :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley Hello! I like your name too. This is the closest I've ever to come to meeting someone with my name. I've read/heard about people named Joran, but I've never actually spoken to or met in person anyone with my name before!

Comment: I know right :P... i met a small child in portland once with our name ... how old are you? Im convinced I am the original(1979) and you guys are all copy cats :P (oh nm your profile says you beat me by at least a few months (since im still 35) :P damn there goes that theory)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Ha HA! I am the alpha and the omega! ;) Yeah, my bday is in February. Weird that we're even about the same age.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by joran, this is because vectors in R are 1-indexed.

Thanks, joran! (And doh!)